# How to interchange data between a DLL and a Visual C# program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using Visual studio.

I have a trading program calling a DLL(written in C# or C++) file for external calculations.
The DLL does several calculations and returns the results.
I have to write the DLL program.

I want this DLL to interchange data with another program that I want to write in C# (or C++) that would be running all the time.

1) How should I do the connection between the DLL and the program that would be running all the time.

2) Is there a different solution for C# and C++?
Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation

Comment: You need an IPC mechanism. There are many options.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api. WebAPI 2 is absolutely fantastic!

Comment: thank you for the answers, I´ll read aboout it.